# Image Gallery Look like Windows Phone 7 - Swipe

Tags: gallery, image, swipe-gesture

I need a Image gallery look like in Windows Phone where when we swipe from the left , the other half of the image is seen and if the image is drag more than 220 width of the image , it should roolback to its original position. I am currently using listbox to get the images dynamically and when using Gestures Drag for swiping. I would like to do some animation so that it exactly behaves as it is seen in Windows Phone 7 Picture Gallery 
Here is the piece of code for the same
private void gestur_DragCompleted(object sender, DragCompletedGestureEventArgs e)
        {
            double len = 0.0;
            double sc = 0.0;
            if (e.Direction == System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal)
            {
                 sw = (ScrollViewer)((VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(OfferImage, 0) as FrameworkElement).FindName("ScrollViewer"));
                 sw.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;

```
            len = sw.HorizontalOffset;
            var abs = PANEL_DRAG_HORIZONTAL;
            if (abs < 0)
            {

                if (abs < 0 && CurrentItem < IamgeList.Count)
                {
                    //flick right

                    sc = 455.0 * CurrentItem;
                    CurrentItem++;
                    sw.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(sc);

                }
```

Comment: Did you got your answer. If yes I am really trying to do that but I am only able to swipe images but not like photo gallery of windows phone. If you can post your answer it will be a help.